# Android: receive dialer number press from the other party

Tags: java, android, telephony

I'm wondering if it's possible to receive a notification if user presses a number in dialer on the other side of connection during the phone call. Like the scheme used by various automated support services - "Press 1 to..., press 2 to...". So I would like to receive that number pressed.

Thanks

Comment: Good question. I'd like to know how this is done too

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible to tap into the phone's incoming audio stream...

There's a lot of "record incoming call" issues on that matter.

You would need the incoming audio stream to read the [DTMF-codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTMF) being sent.